# Call method in a disposable object at the beginning of a "using" statement

Tags: c#, .net

When we use the `lock` statement, it is essentially doing a `Monitor.Enter` at the beginning of the locking block and a `Monitor.Exit` at the end of the block. This process is automatically handled by the runtime.

A similar behaviour is at the end of the `using` block, it calls the `Dispose` method of `IDisposable`.

My question is, that if there is a way to call a method in the disposable object automatically at the beginning of the `using` block.

The reason I want to do this is that, I have implemented a custom `ObservableCollection<T>` that has 2 extra methods: `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate`. They are used to signal a batch update process. The collection won't raise the collection changed event until `EndUpdate` is called.

Although it's perfectly fine to call the 2 methods manually at the beginning and end of the batch process, but it'd be really nice if I can do something like this:

```
using(myCollection)
  foreach(var item in anotherBigList)
    myCollection.Add(item);
```

Comment: It's *exactly* doing a `Monitor.Enter` at the beginning of the block and `Monitor.Exit` at the end. The `lock` keyword is just syntactical sugar that gets transformed into Monitor calls by the compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First I don't like using IDisposable on actual collection. It muddles the actual meaning of Disposable.

I would do it like this:

```
public class CollectionUpdateContext<T>: IDisposable // can also be inner class of custom collection
{
    public CollectionUpdateContext(ObservableCollection<T> inner)
    {
        inner.BeginUpdate();
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
        inner.EndUpdate();
    }
}

public class CustomCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    // whatever code of custom collection

    CollectionUpdateContext<T> Updating() // this can be also as extension method
    {
        return new CollectionUpdateContext<T>(this);
    }
}

using(myCollection.Updating())
  foreach(var item in anotherBigList)
    myCollection.Add(item);
```

This way, it is clear that the using block is related to update mechanics of your collection. Also, because the `IDisposable` is not in custom collection, it forces programmer to call the `Updating` method. And lastly, it doesn't muddle the custom collection by adding `IDisposable`, that has different meaning.

Comment: ? While I understand the intention of your example, how/where is `CollectionUpdateContext<T>.UpdatingCollection` being called? Did you perhaps intend `UpdatingCollection` to be the constructor of `CollectionUpdateContext<T>`?

Comment: @MarjanVenema Sorry, yes. I didn't try to run the code, so I couldn't get compiler do the check.

Comment: this seems like abusing the `using` mechanism...